# BirdView transformations results in black image

Tags: python, c++, opencv, homography

I am trying to implement the following [paper](http://site.uottawa.ca/~laganier/publications/topVI00.pdf) which transforms an image to the bird view perspective, but when I do it using the following code, it doesn't give me the expected result.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

tilt = np.pi * 35 / 180

src = cv2.imread("images/aaa.png")

width, height, depth = src.shape

# Intrinsic parameters of the Camera
calibrate = np.array([[1000, 0, 800],
                      [0, 1200, 100],
                      [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)

# The transformation matrix
b = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
              [0, np.sin(tilt), -np.sin(tilt)],
              [0, np.cos(tilt), np.cos(tilt)]], dtype=np.float32)

# Homography Matrix
result = np.mat(calibrate) * np.mat(b)

print result

output = cv2.warpPerspective(src, result, (height, width))

cv2.imwrite("theresult.png", output)

print output
```

The source image is:

[image: source]

The result supposed to be computed:

[image: result]

The result I get:

[image: result_2]

I don't know what's wrong because I am doing exactly like the paper presents. If there's an alternative to this, even if it was C++ please do provide me with it.

Comment: I can tell you that the total Homography (H including C already in paper - formula 6) between source and supposed result should be something near: `[2.2, 6.7, -181; -0.4, 14.3, -637; 0, 0.03, 1]` but I can't see a way to multiply C with a matrix that has zero top and left side to get that result

Comment: That's Awesome! If I may ask though, how did you get this Matrix? And can you reverse engineer the matrix to get an equation? You're help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I got the matrix by manually selecting point correspondences in both images and compute the homography from that. In the paper I dont understand the assumptions to set one column of M to zero and how to get from (5) to (6) so maybe there is a problem about those assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem. right now i am doing it with:

```
*import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('9.png')
rows,cols,ch = img.shape

pts1 = np.float32([[0,40],[300,40],[0,400],[300,400]])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[100,400],[200,400]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(300,300))

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
plt.show()*
```

this gives me this result:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9cOX.png)

i hope it's helpful